# 1000hz bootstrap validator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I tried to use the 1000hz validator for my forms with basic bootstrap HTML 5 and I have not used any custom query and I don't know it. I used a text field which accepts 10 digit phone number. I modified my code as provided in the example of 1000hz github bootstrap validator. But when I started to type a few numbers it shows a tick mark at the end of the box and when i switch to the next element it does not show a x mark as per validation of HTML 5. I want to show tick mark only when the user enters 10 digits. if reverts back and removes a few digits it should show the x mark till he enter 10 digits. Please help Thanks.

```
<div class="form-group textareawidth has-feedback">
    <label for="mobile">Principal's Mobile number </label>
    <input type ="text"  minlength = "10" maxlength="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter mobile number" name = "hmmobile" id="mobile" data-error="Phone number is invalid" required>
    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="help-block with-errors">Please enter 10 digit number</span>
</div>
```

Another point one user pointed my to use 1000hz its enough to include validator.js. But it didn't work I need to include some more files. Then the example provided in the site works. Am I correct as I am a newbie.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.9.0/validator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ site.cdn_bootstrap_js }}"></script>
<script src="dist/validator.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/application.js"></script>
```

These are the files included.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use data-attribute `data-minlength` to check and validate the length of character in input [Check Reference Here](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-markup)

replace `minlength = "10"` with `data-minlength = "10"`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.9.0/validator.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
    <div class="form-group textareawidth has-feedback">
        <label for="mobile">Principal's Mobile number</label>
        <input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]{1,}$" data-minlength="10" maxlength="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter mobile number" name="hmmobile" id="mobile" data-error="Phone number is invalid" required> <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 <span class="help-block with-errors">Please enter 10 digit number</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

SideNote: you have `1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.9.0/validator.min.js` above `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` and then again `<script src="dist/validator.min.js"></script>`.

Can't have `validator.min.js` lib twice so remove the first which is before the `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`

Comment: It accepts 10 characters even after the pattern ^[0-9]{10}$ and says ok. for ex aaaaaaaaaa is ok

Comment: I am very grateful to you for your answer. Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer and code snippet,  added `pattern="^[0-9]{1,}$"` and it doesn't say `aaaaaaaaaa` is ok, it says it's invalid

Comment: I tried to include a php file which consists of code to populate the list box in the form. But when I include the php file above the entire form disappears. Why and what to do? thanks

Comment: change `include` to `require` and it will tell you what's wrong OR enable the error reporting `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);?>`